# Broken Android Launcher Shortcut due to Extending Application class

Tags: android, shortcut, launcher

So in an effort to refactor my code I introduced a custom application class to my app by extending Application class and including 'android:name=".MyApp"' in the manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
```

The problem I face is that this broke the launcher shortcut for a number of my users after they downloaded the update. Its an issue as some uninstall the app in confusion, this impacts my metrics.

Rolling back now isnt an option as it will break the shortcut again.

The reason why I believe its the addition of the name attribute in the application tag is because I am actually able to reproduce this consistently on a number of test devices. On some this creates a duplicate shortcut on the home screen and in the app drawer. And on others breaks the home screen shortcut  and users see "App isnt installed" message.

Any advice or recommendations on how to deal with this? Thanks.

Comment: Please post your new and your old manifests, especially the definition for the root Activity (the one with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER.).

Comment: There is no reason for this to break your app unless there are problems with your code. So lets see the code.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this issue by adding / removing / changing the name attribute in the application tag. I've updated the question to clarify.